# Trying to compare results against previous results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I am tasked with writing a report that pulls orders according to the line items in that order.  Once I get the correct results I'll use SSRS to create the report for the end users.  Basically what I need to do is query a table that has sales order numbers, line items, date, etc.  Each order has multiple line items. They want to know if an order has a line item called ASR, SERVICE, or if neither of them are in there.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    arcust.loctid, 
    sodate, 
    somast.custno, 
    somast.sono, 
    somast.route, 
    item
FROM 
    somast
    INNER JOIN arcust ON somast.custno = arcust.custno
    INNER JOIN sotran ON somast.sono = sotran.sono
WHERE 
    sodate = '06-04-2015' AND 
    somast.sostat NOT IN('X','V') AND
    route IN ('220','221')
```

This is what I am using but it is pulling all line items.  How can I only pull one line item per order if it has the line item ASR or SERVICE or neither of those?

Here are the results of that query:

```
loctid                sodate    custno      sono  route item
OMAHA   2015-06-04 00:00:00.000 10268      4399062  221 10788          
OMAHA   2015-06-04 00:00:00.000 10268      4399062  221 SALESDEL       
OMAHA   2015-06-04 00:00:00.000 2298       4399308  221 10291          
OMAHA   2015-06-04 00:00:00.000 2298       4399308  221 10445          
OMAHA   2015-06-04 00:00:00.000 2298       4399308  221 10448          
OMAHA   2015-06-04 00:00:00.000 2298       4399308  221 10751          
OMAHA   2015-06-04 00:00:00.000 2298       4399308  221 21016          
OMAHA   2015-06-04 00:00:00.000 2298       4399308  221 21030          
OMAHA   2015-06-04 00:00:00.000 2298       4399308  221 23002          
OMAHA   2015-06-04 00:00:00.000 2298       4399308  221 66262          
OMAHA   2015-06-04 00:00:00.000 2298       4399308  221 ASR            
OMAHA   2015-06-04 00:00:00.000 2513       4399451  221 10329          
OMAHA   2015-06-04 00:00:00.000 2513       4399451  221 10520          
OMAHA   2015-06-04 00:00:00.000 2513       4399451  221 10910          
OMAHA   2015-06-04 00:00:00.000 2513       4399451  221 11010          
OMAHA   2015-06-04 00:00:00.000 2513       4399451  221 21772          
OMAHA   2015-06-04 00:00:00.000 2513       4399451  221 SALESDEL       
OMAHA   2015-06-04 00:00:00.000 514        4399287  221 11437          
OMAHA   2015-06-04 00:00:00.000 514        4399287  221 SERVICE         
OMAHA   2015-06-04 00:00:00.000 8449       4399314  221 30405
```

I would like to see it like this:

```
loctid                sodate    custno      sono  route item

OMAHA   2015-06-04 00:00:00.000 10268      4399062  221 SALESDEL         
OMAHA   2015-06-04 00:00:00.000 2298       4399308  221 ASR            
OMAHA   2015-06-04 00:00:00.000 2513       4399451  221 10329          
OMAHA   2015-06-04 00:00:00.000 514        4399287  221 SERVICE           
OMAHA   2015-06-04 00:00:00.000 8449       4399314  221 30405
```

Comment: JamesZ - I jsut want it to pull the line that has ASR or SERVICE or if neither are in the order then I would like to somehow know that neither are in the order

Comment: In your desired results, why does custno 10268 have SALESDEL, but 2513 has '10329', when SALESDEL is one of the items?   In any event, you should be able to do what you want with a CASE WHEN EXISTS() statement.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are useing the wrong type of join.  Take a look at this graph.  I use this all the time and is super helpful.

[image]